# Hide tooltip onmouseover for Google Visualization API

Tags: api, google-visualization, onmouseover, pie-chart

Is there any way to hide the popup when a pie slice is moused-over in the Google Visualization API using Pie Charts? Thanks

Comment: I would seriously like to know the answer to this, too. It's hard to believe there isn't some kind of boolean flag to turn the buggers off.

Answer (score 4):

To remove the tooltips you have to do it this way:

```
chart.draw(data, {tooltip: {trigger:'none'}});
```

You can also remove all interactivity if you don't want your graph to react to any user actions:

```
chart.draw(data, {enableInteractivity: false});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try to set trigger to 'none

```
chart.draw(data, {trigger:'none'});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to turn on/off the tooltip currently. But following could do the trick:

```
tooltip_iframe = window.frames[document.getElementById('your chart id').firstChild.name];
tooltip_dom = tooltip_iframe.document.getElementById('chart').firstChild.nextSibling.nextSibling;
tooltip_dom.style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

```
 var options = { 
    tooltip: {trigger:'none'}
     };
    chart.draw(data, options);
```